# Which is the best database to use to index the internet?

Tags: database

If you had to make provision for 80 million records (one for each page on the internet) and store the relationships between those records (which is 80 billion to the nth power), which database would be the best for this?

I've started this project thinking we will only map a portion of the internet, but unfortunately it has gone far beyond the limits of mysql. I need a better way to keep track of this data. The frontend is PHP, but I suppose the backend can be anything, as long as it can handle that amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i won't say there is the one holy database for your needs, maybe it could be better for your company to split your database in logical parts to handle the amount of data in a better way. maybe you could outsource some data into file system as you won't need anything everytime in your database.

if you scan the interwebs, you probably save the html, css or any big data you crawl for into your filesystem while you save connections and everything meta related into your database. but i really think you'd mentioned that already.

the best advice i want to give here is to make sure, your structure of your database is whatever fits your processes the best before think about switching the database. if you really need to switch (as mysql would not give you more performance), there will be mongodb and/or webscalesql. webscale seems to be used by facebook to handle the amount of their data.

a big question would be if you just can improve your performance by improve your hardware. you should check that too, AFTER you checked your structure and processes!